# Specify mocked method's return value entirely regardless of parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Say I have a mock that contains a method `public int Add(int, int)` and I want the mock to return `5` is there way to specify that any call on `AddTwoNumbers` returns `5`?

I already know I can use

```
mock.Setup(n => n.Add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(5);
```

but if the add method changes to use floats, or more than two ints then tests using this break whereas being able to say 'all calls to Add return 5' would help with decoupling the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do this with Moq.  The only API Moq exposes to specify the return the value of a method is the one you've shown.  And obviously performing this setup requires the type parameters to match in order to compile.  I think you're looking for a more loosely-typed API, something like:

```
mock.SetupMethodsNamed("Add").Returns(5);
```

If this is what you're looking for, feel free to [open an issue with the Moq project](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues); they're generally pretty open to suggestions and may be able to point out issues with this approach or why it isn't implemented.

However, I do not see any real benefit of doing this.  If you're trying to protect your code from future changes, then how can you know that `5` will always be a sensible return type?  If you're just trying to save some work (i.e. set up the `int` overload and the `float` overload in one shot), then just write a method to do them both and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue tracker, might just do that and see if anything comes of it. The aim is to not have a large number of tests break because one method now has an additional parameter, though obviously some tests should break because of this which might then show `5` isn't an acceptable return.